# ¿Cómo trabajar una función asíncrona?

Tags: javascript

¡Hola Comunidad! espero se encuentren muy bien.

Tengo la siguiente situación, estoy trabajando con la clase `FileReader` que funciona de forma asíncrona, mi intención es cargar un archivo **Excel** o **CSV** para realizar una  conversión a formato **JSON** y luego realizar una validación, como lo muestra la siguiente función:

```
function validarArchivo(control) {
    var files = control[0].files, f = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    //Se guarda el control que disparó el evento para su validación posterior   
    controlFile = control;
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'array'});

      var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

      var excelJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);    
      validarCoordenadas(excelJson);      
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```

La situación es que el llamado a la función `validarCoordenadas()`, solo se ejecuta una vez la función que invoca `validarArchivo()` ha culminado, razón por la cual no obtengo el resultado esperado ¿Qué podría hacer para obtener primero el resultado de `validarCoordenadas()` y luego pueda seguir el flujo normal de la función previa?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Podrías convertir la función `validarCoordenadas()` en una `new Promise()`, puedes agregar el código de `validarCoordenadas()` ? El problema está ahí no en esta función

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```
async function validarArchivo(control) {
    var files = control[0].files, f = files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    //Se guarda el control que disparó el evento para su validación posterior   
    controlFile = control;
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      var data = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
      var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {type: 'array'});

      var first_sheet_name = workbook.SheetNames[0];
      var worksheet = workbook.Sheets[first_sheet_name];

      var excelJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);    
      await validarCoordenadas(excelJson);      
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
}
```

Comment: Podrias explicar que es lo que tiene que intentar? las respuestas con solo codigo se consideran de baja calidad

Comment: Poner la función a ejecutarse de forma síncrona con el async, y esperar la respuesta del método validarCoordenadas(excelJson) con el await.

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda esa explicacion, no para mi, si no para todos los futuros lectores de tu respuesta, y asi se entiende porque este codigo es la respuesta. Tambien explica como esperar la respuesta. ;)

Comment: Leandro, agradezco tu ayuda, solo tuve que hacer una modificación. Tuve que agregar async en la función anónima de reader.onload = async function() { }, ya que no me reconocía el await dado que estaba en esta función anónima. Ahora sí funciona correctamente la validación, gracias!